# no duplicates in listbox when using values from excel in tkinter python?

Tags: python, tkinter, duplicates

I need to avoid duplicates in a tkinter listbox. The values are taken from a column in excel, and same values will apear several times.
I have tryed to use sort, but that dosent work.
Any sugestions?

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from openpyxl.workbook import workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

root = Tk()
root.title("Test")
root.geometry("500x500")

#Create workbook
#wb = Workbook()
#Load existing  workbook
wb = load_workbook('Test.xlsx')
# Create active worksheet
ws = wb.active

my_listbox = Listbox(root, width=40)
my_listbox.pack(pady=20)

#create variable for column
column_a = ws['A']

for item in column_a:
   my_listbox.insert(END, item.value)
my_listbox.delete(0)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) rather than a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list). Sets have a lot in common, but all values are unique. This makes it useful for easily removing duplicates.

```
values_loaded = { item.value for item in column_a }
for entry in values_loaded:
   my_listbox.insert(END, entry)
```

You might be able to shorten it to:

```
values_loaded = { item.value for item in column_a }
my_listbox.insert(END, *values_loaded)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, both for your explaination. Both your answers works, but I can only give one of you points. I really helped me. Thank you so much again .-)

Answer (score 2):

Python sets are the go-to way to remove duplicates with a minimum of fuss.  In your case, after retrieving `column_a`, but before populating your listbox, build a set of `item.value`s then populate your listbox from that set.

Example:

```
column_a = ws['A']

my_values = {
   item.value
   for item in column_a
}

for value in my_values:
   my_listbox.insert(END, value)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, both for your explaination. Both your answers works, but I can only give one of you points. I really helped me. Thank you so much again .-)

Comment: LOL - the important thing is you got what you came for!  Best wishes.